# Bluetooth Software

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

Is there any third-party software that takes over the functionality of the built-in Windows Bluetooth software?

I have a Bluetooth chip in my computer and Windows recognizes it just fine, but I have multiple headsets that just don't work correctly with it. Some functionality of the headset is always missing; sometimes it's the ability to answer a call with the main button, other times the headset won't remain the default communication device.

I'm looking for some software that makes it easier to pair the Bluetooth device with the computer and assign functionality to the different features of the Bluetooth device